How can I archive my website for offline/online use (wget) that needs multiple domains?
I'm trying to archive an old PHP website offline. The goal is to have all the website data in one folder ...

So that I can browse through everything offline
I can upload the folder and then browse the site WITHOUT PHP / statically

It's an old PHP site that is no longer maintained and should therefore go "offline", but for the purpose of archiving...
It's not about members area either - so really just everything that can be accessed online without logging in etc.
I'm currently playing around with the following command:
URL="http://www.example.org"
OPTIONS="--recursive --convert-links --page-requisites -E"
wget $OPTIONS $URL

My problem is the following:

Some data comes from other domains (root.example.org, site2.example.org, example.org) how can I integrate this? (I didn't manage to do it with span-hosts in a folder - which works on/off-line, or how to fix this)

although I don't think Google Analytics has to be in the new one - I think :)


How can I stop the download process and start it again?
What's the best way to check whether I have everything?

